# Error on remove duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I keep on getting an

> invalid procedure call or argument - Run-Time ERROR '5'

when I remove duplicates on a sheet.

```
 With sh.Range("$A$1:G" & Sh.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
        ReDim iArray(1 To .Columns.Count)
        For i = 1 To UBound(iArray)
            iArray(i) = i
        Next i
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(iArray), header:=xlYes
 end With
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why use loop? You can directly input it using `Array()` function.

Comment: Because the Array () variable was also failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array keys needs to start with `0` not with `1` I think.

```
 With sh.Range("$A$1:G" & Sh.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
        ReDim iArray(0 To .Columns.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(iArray)
            iArray(i) = i + 1
        Next i
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(iArray), header:=xlYes
 end With
```

This results in an array like

```
(key) = value
(0)   = 1
(1)   = 2
(2)   = 3
...
(6)   = 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had switched on Option Base 1